# Recording the date an object is added to a has_many collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Users on my site each have one list, which consists of a different type of users. I'm using a has_many through relationship to do this as follows:

List.rb:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :list_applicants
  has_many :applicants, through: :list_applicants
end
```

Applicant.rb:

```
class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :list_applicants
  has_many :lists, through: :list_applicants
end
```

ListApplicant.rb

```
class ListApplicant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :applicant_id, :list_id
  belongs_to :applicant
  belongs_to :list
end
```

Company.rb:

```
 class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :list
 end
```

When a user adds another user to their list, I'd like to record the date the user is added so they can sort their list of users by date added. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `created_at` field of the `ListApplicant` model if it has one. If not, you may add manually a similar field.

UPDATE:

You can access the field by specifying both applicant and list like this:

```
@applicant.list_applicants.where(list_id: @list.id).first.created_at
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing that, but how would I access it?

Comment: Just add them like you would add any other column; create a migration with `add_column(:list_applicants, :created_at, :datetime)`

Comment: Okay I wasn't clear there. If I'm iterating through the list of applicants creating a table where each row is a rendered partial of info about the applicant which is fetched through the local variable applicant, what do I call created_at on to produce the date added info?

Comment: You call created_at on the join model, the ListApplicant, to see when the connection was added.